# Linux: how to run a program with rw access to only a folder

Tags: linux, permissions, chroot

How can I execute a program in a way that all the system is RO and only some folders are RW?

Eg: steam (:P)

```
roexec --rw ~/.steam steam
```

Is there any tool that allows me to do this?
I've tried `mount -o bind,ro / ...` and then `mount -o bind,rw ~/.steam ...` but they doesn't seem to work...

Comment: The "right" way would be to use something like AppArmor. If your distro uses it (like Ubuntu), check out some of the profiles in `/etc/apparmor.d`. Unless you run `steam` under its own user.